# C pointer with char[], const keyword ignored?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I made a little function in C which copies a `char` array. I didn't want `source` to be changed, so I put `const` into the function declaration and body, but ***it changed.***

main.c

```
#include "copy_char.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char source[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
  char dest[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };

  printf("%s\n", source); // hello
  printf("%s\n", dest); // abc

  copy_char(source, dest);
  
  printf("%s\n", source); // o (?) - why did this change? 
  printf("%s\n", dest); // hello
}
```

copy_char.c

```
#include "copy_char.h"

void copy_char(const char* source, char* dest)
{
  while(*source != 0)
  {
    *dest++ = *source++; 
  }

  *dest = 0;
}
```

copy_char.h

```
#ifndef COPYCHAR_H
#define COPYCHAR_H

void copy_char(const char* source, char* dest);

#endif /* COPYCHAR_H */
```

Can anyone explain to me, why did my `source` char array change from `hello` to `o`?

Comment: You have Undefined Behaviour because you overflow the `dest` buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffer overrun. The string `source` is longer than the memory allocated for `dest`, so when you copy `source` to `dest` you are tromping over memory you didn't intend to. Weird things then happen (undefined behavior).

You can make `dest` big enough by declaring its size to be big enough for "hello":

```
char dest[6] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
```

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't want source to be changed, so I put const into function declaration and body. but, it changed

The `const` qualifier does not magically protect you from writing where you should not. It's merely a contract between you and the compiler that says "trust me, I am not going to modify the memory pointed to by this pointer".

In your function you are writing data past the end of `dest`, which is undefined behavior. You should either:

1. Pass a maximum length to the function:

   ```c
   void copy_char(const char* source, char* dest, size_t maxlen)
   {
     size_t i;

     for (i = 0; i < maxlen && source[i]; i++)
     {
       dest[i] = source[i];
     }

     dest[i] = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Stop at either `*source == 0` or `*dest == 0`:

   ```c
   void copy_char(const char* source, char* dest)
   {
     while(*source != 0 && *dest != 0)
     {
       *dest++ = *source++; 
     }

     *dest = 0;
   }
   ```
3. Create a big enough `dest` array and leave the function unchanged.

The semantics of the function change depending on which option you choose, which one is the right one is up to you.

What most likely is happening in your case is that it just so happens that `source` is right past the end of `dest`, so you overwrite the contents of `dest` with `'h','e','l','l'`, then the first character of `source` with `'o'` and then the second one with `'\0'`. Luckily enough, your program does not crash, and you end up with a valid string in `source` that is `"o"`. Nonetheless, you should **never rely on undefined behavior**, whether your program seems to magically work or not.

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll just note that one should never *depend* on the behavior described in the last paragraph. I think it is absolutely correct in describing what is causing the observed behavior, but it could change with a different compiler, compiler version, compiler options (such as optimization), etc. Undefined behavior is, after all, undefined.

Comment: @FredLarson indeed. Let me just state it for clarity.

Comment: Ooh, I think there's an off-by-one bug in your example with the maximum size. It may write the null terminator one byte past the end of the buffer.

Comment: @FredLarson depends on the semantics you assign to `n`... in my case I use it as a max length (so you write at most `n + 1`), let me rename the variable to make it clearer.

Comment: I can see that. I was thinking of if you passed `sizeof(dest)` to the function. If you passed in `strlen(dest)` instead, it would work. I would favor going by the size of the buffer rather than the length of the string that's already in it. Whatever works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It helps me a lot. One question, why did you guess that `<source> is right past the end of <dest>` ? I declared <source> first and then <dest> @Fred

Comment: @JinLim the order of declaration doesn't matter, the compiler can re-arrange variables on the stack however it wants. Indeed, it's most common to see them in reverse order of declaration.

Comment: @Marco Maybe because it will be on `stack` memory? Last In First Out.

Comment: @JinLim yes, I would argue that's the reason for them being usually reversed, but as I said you should not assume that they always are, it's up to the compiler to decide how to order variables on the stack.